# GnuPG: Get Public Key/Fingeprint from Encrypted mail

Tags: email, encryption, gnupg

I have received a GnuPG encrypted mail which i cant decrypt:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Charset: ISO-8859-15
Version: GnuPG v2.0.20 (MingW32)
Comment: Using GnuPG with Thunderbird - http://www.enigmail.net/

.............+AWJjL0Un8xWK0lFgw26Oos
ynzsVjy9fZAVlzoVN3XgucjIG8guTrakLbbvF0aMwDIwUXb3x1b+4hGNmkx+TUQV
kE6WcnnJw5B+8/m3CQ+IxbalHKAOu7VRHZ7XJCvY6dLAIQGSmwx77S3TV4zKH5PR
p3e15GJbcM+Gfo9Ka8u6KtGZALEk9xsZjH3QmfyB66dARp4/u7gJZrJ9hd5bzXJ9
LfjEvqygdpTeak2etz+r90WbiC/P4mnXQoxz7s3m1nJESb6VcpipJFkfwFdl1BYx
0XVfY/uH/gkQGiPNQL.....................O87w==
=Cnbj
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Is there a way i can figure out which public key/Fingerprint was used to encrypt this message?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pgpdump`, which is available in all relevant package repositories.

```
$ cat <<EOT | pgpdump
> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
> Charset: ISO-8859-15
> Version: GnuPG v2.0.20 (MingW32)
> Comment: Using GnuPG with Thunderbird - http://www.enigmail.net/
>
> .............+AWJjL0Un8xWK0lFgw26Oos
> ynzsVjy9fZAVlzoVN3XgucjIG8guTrakLbbvF0aMwDIwUXb3x1b+4hGNmkx+TUQV
> kE6WcnnJw5B+8/m3CQ+IxbalHKAOu7VRHZ7XJCvY6dLAIQGSmwx77S3TV4zKH5PR
> p3e15GJbcM+Gfo9Ka8u6KtGZALEk9xsZjH3QmfyB66dARp4/u7gJZrJ9hd5bzXJ9
> LfjEvqygdpTeak2etz+r90WbiC/P4mnXQoxz7s3m1nJESb6VcpipJFkfwFdl1BYx
> 0XVfY/uH/gkQGiPNQL.....................O87w==
> =Cnbj
> -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
> EOT
```

Given the full message, it will output the key that was encrypted to (with the input provided, it will only show an error message).